# Angular x-editable using setter instead of model field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

In my angular controller, my model does not exactly reflect the way the data is displayed on the screen. To display the data anyway, I use a method bound to `$scope` to extract the data to show.

```
<a href='#' editable-text="???" onaftersave='setData($data)'>
  {{ getData() }}
</a>
```

Showing the data works fine, but saving doesn't. Lacking an alternative, I used `onaftersave` to save the data. However, it seems that one needs to specify `editable-text` in order to get x-editable to work. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answer my own question (in hope it's of use for anyone who stumbles upon the same problem):
After reading parts of the source code, I think it is not possible to do this. I guess the whole point of having a controller is to transform the data into a format that is easy to display (i.e. in a way that `x-editable` can directly access it).